# Problem with save/load preferences drom a list of objects

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

My **model**,**save** and **load** are:

```
  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    required this.stock,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.quantity
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        price: json['price'],
        stock: json['stock'],
        avatar: json['avatar'],
        quantity: json['quantity'],
    );
  }


  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final int stock;
  final String avatar;
  int quantity;

  List<Product> selectedItems = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['name'] = name;
    map['price'] = price;
    map['stock'] = stock;
    map['avatar'] = avatar;
    map['quantity'] = quantity;
    return map;
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id];

}


void _savePreferences(Product product)async {
    List<Product> cart = [];
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    cart.add(product);
    _prefs.setString('cart', json.encode(cart));
   
  }
_loadPreferences()async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var decodedData= json.decode(prefs.getString('cart') ?? '');
    print(decodedData);
    print(Product.fromJson(decodedData));
    
  }
```

When i print my decoded data it give me something like that:

**[{id: 1, name: Beer, price: 10.0, stock: 300, avatar: https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/beer-mug-2059261-1740592.png, quantity: 4}]**

The next step that i have in my mind is to convert this list is a object of Product using Product.fromJson but i have the next issue:

**type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
#0      _CartPageState._loadPreferences (package:BEBERAPID/app/ui/cart/cart_page.dart:113:28)**

Can u help me guys? save and load prefs aren't in the same class, I only copy  the methods to do faster your read.

Comment: This is not good practice to store lists in shared preferences, you should use SQLite database for this, use Room instead.

Comment: I know, im wating for the backend and the desing of the proyect and they just told me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you get these type casting errors, the error message tells you everything you need to know.

In this case, its telling you that it wants a `Map`, and you're passing in a `list`. I agree with @Praveen you probably want a more capable storage solution. Doesn't have to be SQLite you could also consider Hive or ObjectBox etc...

Either way, here's an example of a way to save a single instance of your `Product` model with SharedPreferences.

```
void savePreferences(Product product) async {
  SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final productMap = product.toJson();  // returns a map that json.encode can use
  _prefs.setString('cart', json.encode(productMap));
}
```

If you wanted to save a `Map` of `Products` you could do something like this.

```
Map masterProductList = {};

void saveToMap(Product product) async {
  masterProductList['${product.id}'] = product.toJson(); // adds a map of the Product object to masterProductList
  SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  _prefs.setString('cart', json.encode(masterProductList));
}
```

That just uses the product id as the key in the map.

After saving multiple `Products` you could print all of them just by printing the map that you stored.

```
var decodedData= json.decode(prefs.getString('cart') ?? '');
    print(decodedData);
```